# StackExchange content scraping with obfuscation

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites, screen-scraping

The topic of content scraping from StackExchange and StackOverflow is very well known. I thought the admins would like to know that the scrapers have boosted their efforts and are now obfuscating words through synonym replacement.

Take for example this StackOverflow question: [React Native AlertIOS error: tried to display alert view but there is no application window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645893/react-native-alertios-error-tried-to-display-alert-view-but-there-is-no-applica/35670611#35670611)

It has now become this: http://www.walkileaks.com/react-native-alertios-error-tried-to-display-alert-view-but-there-is-no-application-window/

Note some key replacements of `application` with `software` and other substitutions.

Comment: Well that's just dumb. If you change the error messages no one will visit you! And if you don't provide the answers at the same time, they won't come back.

Comment: The walkileaks site you linked has been taken down

Comment: @Quill interesting, I wonder if these content scrapers rotate domains or if the admins have a way of dealing with it

Comment: @crockpotveggies usually the hosts take down websites like that, but I don't know